# Toggle page content from spanish to englishwith a click, how to approach this?

Tags: jquery, translation

I have a span element, if that span element is clicked I want to dinamically toggle the content from spanish to english and viceversa, how can I approach this?

```
<li style="font-size:22px; margin-top:8px;">Language:  <span id="" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="" >english</span></li>
```

Comment: depends on how the translations are handled

Comment: the page will be a local page, it will be a surprise for my girlfriend so

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload your webpage with parameters like "index.php?lang=eng".

```js
$(".selectLang li").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var getLang = $(this).data('lang');
  
  window.location.href + "?lang=" + getLang;
  console.log(window.location.href + "?lang=" + getLang);
});
```

```css
ul { list-style-type : none }
li { cursor:pointer }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="selectLang">
  <li style="font-size:22px; margin-top:8px;" data-lang="eng">Language:  <span>english</span></li>
  <li style="font-size:22px; margin-top:8px;" data-lang="spa">Language:  <span>spanish</span></li>
</ul>
```

Or with ajax with two text files (text-eng.txt and text-spa.txt).

```js
$(".selectLang li").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var getLang = $(this).data('lang');
  
  $.ajax({
      url : "text-" + getLang + ".txt",
      dataType: "text",
      success : function (data) {
          $(".text").html(data);
      }
  });
});
```

```css
ul { list-style-type : none }
li { cursor:pointer }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="selectLang">
  <li style="font-size:22px; margin-top:8px;" data-lang="eng">Language:  <span>english</span></li>
  <li style="font-size:22px; margin-top:8px;" data-lang="spa">Language:  <span>spanish</span></li>
</ul>

<div class="text"></div>
```